# CSS media query does not response to given max-width or min-width

Tags: html, css

In CSS when I mention (max-width: 800px) browser should load that style when screen reaches 800px but my browser load that style in 720px why that's happening?

This is CSS media query

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #header-home {
    height: 30rem;
    .header-content {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

It's not working after it reaches below 800px width of screen. But it works when screen reaches below 720px

[image]

Comment: You mixed up min-width and max-width. 720px is within a max-width of 800px.

Comment: This is not CSS. If you have a question about how to do something in CSS, compile your preprocessed code into CSS and share that here along with the markup necessary to comprise a [mcve]. If you have a question about how to do something in Sass that you can get working in CSS, please use the [tag:sass] tag, instead.

Comment: It is not css but in css also I am facing this problem.

Comment: From that picture you have zoom applied reset it and it'll work as expected

Comment: @ZohirSalak That's it bro. Thanks a lot :). Everyone thinking that I am mixing up max-width and min-width but its not. its browser zoom problem. I got it bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong, it should load the style up to 800px

you should do this:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #header-home {
    height: 30rem;
    .header-content {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not mix up with min or max width.... in max-width 800px Google Chorme should load the style when scrren is at least 800px and lower but Chorme load that style only after when it reaches 720px... but it should load that style in 800px...

Comment: dude your mixin it up 
max-width="800" means the style will load  up to 800px, min-width:800px means the style will load from 800px and up

Answer (score -1):

You have two mistakes.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px)  {
  #header-home {
    height: 30rem;
    .header-content {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

You need to add `only screen and` before you specify width and you want to change the style when the MINIMUM WIDTH OF SCREEN IS 800PX. So, it will not be `max-width` it will be `min-width`

If it continues this means the problem is not here. It seems other elements on the page causing it. It maybe the image or the button margins

Comment: I want to load that style 800px and lower not higher. That's why I am using max-width: 800px. But Google Chrome loading this style when its 720px. it should load that style in 800px or 799px.

Comment: Having `only screen and` or not doesn't breaks the media rule

Comment: @ZohirSalak Absolutely Right Brother

Comment: Then Its working. Isn't it? You are saying you want to load that style when the device width is 800px or lower. So when the width is 720px its loading the css.

Comment: Zohir Salak But sometimes it does. At least i happened to me

Comment: @BrainGamer but it should load at 800px is'nt it?

Comment: now it is loading this problem happend for zoom of my browser scrren

Comment: what your saying is wrong pls delete this answer